# How can I dynamically change Axios request on button click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to dynamically change the req attribute of my axios request on button click.
I'm using SWAPI, then when I call get "people/", it returns "next" as the link for the next page.
When I click the button, I want to change the request to "next" attribute retrieved from the api.

```js
<template>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li v-bind:key="person.birth_year" v-for="person of people" class="response">
      <div class="card">
          <h1>{{person.name}}</h1>
          <h3>Altura: {{person.height}}</h3>
          <h3>Peso: {{person.mass}}</h3>
          <h3>Gênero: {{person.gender}}</h3>
          <h3>Cor da pele: {{person.skin_color}}</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <button v-on:click="req=next">Proxima Pagina</button>
  </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import api from '../services/api'

import '../css/index.css'

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      people:[],
      next:"",      
      req:""
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    let req="people/"
      api.get(req)
      .then(response=>{
        this.people=response.data.results;
        this.next=response.data.next;
      });
  },

}
</script>
```

Comment: Add a proper click handler function for the button. In that click handler, do the request based on `this.next`. When it finishes, update `this.next`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same variable to set the new link as below :

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li v-bind:key="person.birth_year" v-for="person of people" class="response">
                <div class="card">
                    <h1>{{person.name}}</h1>
                    <h3>Altura: {{person.height}}</h3>
                    <h3>Peso: {{person.mass}}</h3>
                    <h3>Gênero: {{person.gender}}</h3>
                    <h3>Cor da pele: {{person.skin_color}}</h3>
                </div>
            </li>
            <button v-on:click="getData()">Proxima Pagina</button>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import api from '../services/api'

    import '../css/index.css'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                people: [],
                next: "",
                req: "people/"
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.getData();
        },
        methods: {

            getData() {
                api.get(this.req).then(response => {
                    this.people = response.data.results;
                    this.req = response.data.next;
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```